Ktor загрузка файла в виде ByteArray
Я получаю ByteArray с камеры в и пытаюсь его загрузить на сервер так.
val response = client.post(url) {
    setBody(
        MultiPartFormDataContent(
            formData {
                if (byteArrays != null) {
                    append("image", byteArrays, Headers.build {
                        append(HttpHeaders.ContentType, "image/png")
                        append(HttpHeaders.ContentDisposition, "filename=${name}")
                    })
                }
            },
        )
    )
    onUpload { bytesSentTotal, contentLength ->
        println("Sent $bytesSentTotal bytes from $contentLength")
    }
}

Но получаю в ответ "Required request part 'file' is not present"

В ответе все написано, вы отправляете image, а сервер ждет file. Обратитесь к его документации.
